# warning: statement with no effect wunused value

Tags: c, warnings

I would be grateful if someone can help me with this.
I am a beginner in coding and typed a program in c using the switch control expression
To determine if an integer is odd or even and I keep getting this warning on Code Blocks.

**warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]|** in lines 15 and 21.

I have tried to Google the issue but each solution appears vague like one stated that the problem lies with assigning a value to the result.
The program is below

```
1. #include<stdio.h> 
2. #include<stdlib.h> 
3. 
4. int main() 
5. { 
6.     int num; 
7. 
8.     printf("Enter the integer\n"); 
9.     scanf("%d", &num); 
10. 
11. 
12.     switch(num % 2) 
13.     {
14.     case 0: 
15.         num % 2 == 0;
16.         printf("Number is even");   
17.         break; 
18.    
19.     
20.     case 1: 
21.         num % 2 !=0; 
22.         printf("Number is Odd");
23.         break;
24.      }
25.     
26. Return 0;
27. 
28. }
29.
```

Really appreciate the help.

Regards.

Comment: What do you think a statement like `num%2 == 0;` does? Why did you put this statement in your program?

Comment: Re “I have tried to Google…”: Are you learning from a book or what? A book teaching C should teach you the concepts as you need and should lead you through them. There should be no need to Google anything at this level.

Comment: Hi , Eric, I am doing this with a beginners book which put up this problem at the end  of the chapter about Selection Structures and the problem was about asking the user to enter an integer and then the compiler uses a switch expression structure along with mod division to compile it. Its a beginners book but the problems are beyond my IQ level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means exactly what your compiler tells you: The statements

```
num%2 !=0;
```

and

```
num%2 == 0;
```

do not have an effect and can be removed. These are comparisons, but the comparison result is not used (i.e. discarded).

The conditional is already here:

```
switch(num%2)
```

and the result is used with the `case` statements.

Maybe the statements with no effect were meant to be comments? Then prefix them with `//`

Comment: I did what you suggested and removed the statements num%2 = 0 and num%2 != 0. The warnings have now disappeared.  So how is it that if I use a switch expression stating num%2  will tell the compiler which case option to pick as I have no where stated the option of num%2 == 0 or num%2!=0.

Comment: @RaseshRao: As the book undoubtedly tells you, when you write `switch (num%2)`, the program evaluates `num%2` and uses the result to decide where to jump to. The labels `case 0:` and `case 1:` mark where to jump to if the result is 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

First , in your code switch returns 1 or 0 ,you just make "case 0:" and "case 1:"

Second ,change Return to return

```
int main()
{
    int num;

   printf("Enter the integer\n");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   switch(num%2)
   {
      case 0 :
      printf("Number is even");
      break;
      case 1 :
      printf("Number is Odd");
      break;
   }
    return 0;
 }
```